# Scaling images in a spritesheet in corona

Tags: lua, scaling, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

I've just started using spritesheets in corona so this might be a basic question but I can't find any info regarding it.

Anyway, is it possible to scale the images inside the spritesheet? For example, frame 1 image 1 would be 100x25, frame 2 image 2 would be set to 100x50, frame 3 image 3 150x50.

Answer (score -1):

You can try sprite.newSpriteMultiSet() function
Here is the link:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/sprite/newSpriteMultiSet.html

Comment: In the future consider more helpful answers, like an example piece of code. The above link no longer exists and if it did, it is better to give answers specific to this context rather than have the OP infer from a general tutorial or documentation